# how to integrate speech recognition flutter plugin in quiz app

Tags: flutter, dart, speech-recognition, flutter-dependencies, speech-to-text

I intended to integrate speech_to_text flutter plugin in Quiz app that will give result whether the input user speaks is correct or wrong. This app is actually concerned on the pronunciation - if the user pronounced the word displayed correctly, the system will display correct answer, otherwise vice versa.

Is anyone has any idea what method do I have to compare the input from the user and the correct answer? Do I have to use pre-recorded audio or just a data string of each respective answer(just in Text I mean)? I hope anyone can give their point of view on this. Thank you in advance